# fullcalendar (Premium Scheduler add-on) - reduce the gap between days and show 3 months

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using **fullcalendar - premium Scheduler** add-on to show **3 months** view

But unable to reduce the gap inside the cell content to show all 3 months at once.

**PS**: Not able to simulate jsFiddle example while I am using the licenced version... Sorry for that

**Code:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: '2017-11-07',
    editable: true,
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    header: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,timeline3Months'
    },
    defaultView: 'timeline3Months',
    views: {
      timeline3Months: {
        type: 'timelineMonth',
        slotDuration: { days: 1 },
        duration: { months: 3 }
      }
    },
    buttonText: {
      month: '1 Month',
      timeline3Months: '3 Months',
    },
    navLinks: true,
    events: [
      { id: '1', resourceId: 'b', start: '2017-11-15T02:00:00', end: '2017-12-08T07:00:00', title: 'Event 1' },
    ],
  });   
});
```

**Output:**
[image]

> Show all 3 months without scrolling by reducing the gap between cell
>   content

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hurray!

Got the answer by doing the below

```
slotWidth: 8,
```